How can you configure a MAUI Blazor hybrid app works just with a tap at time?
I'm making an app for Windows computers that uses touch screens, so for protection I need my program to only can use one finger tap at time, avoiding gestures like zoom in or zoom out, go back, etc.
I've tried to adjust it by changing Windows configuration, but it disallows all touch functions. That's why I'm trying to make it by code for my app

For maui , you can use the handler to rewrite the native control and subscribe to native control events such as the gesture event in Handler.
Such as the long press control on each platform.
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ImageHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>  
        {  
#if WINDOWS  
            handler.PlatformView.Holding += PlatformView_Holding;  

#endif  
#if ANDROID  
            handler.PlatformView.LongClick += PlatformView_LongClick;  
  
#endif  
#if IOS   
            handler.PlatformView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;  
            handler.PlatformView.AddGestureRecognizer(new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(HandleLongClick));  
#endif    
        }); 



#if WINDOWS  
    private void PlatformView_Holding(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)  
    {  
        //Touch can produce a Holding action, but mouse devices generally can't.  
        //see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding?view=winrt-22621  
    }  
#endif  
#if IOS  
    private void HandleLongClick(UILongPressGestureRecognizer sender)  
    {  
        //do something  
    }  
#endif  
#if ANDROID  
    private void PlatformView_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)  
    {  
        // do something  
    }  
#endif  

And this is the information you can refer to Invoking Events from Effects
